# Count number of views of a video displayed using active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Using `active storage` I am storing videos in a Lesson model;

```
class Lesson
   has_one_attached :video
end
```

displayed with this code;

```
<div class='feed'>
  <%= render partial: 'lesson', collection: @lessons, cached: true %>
</div>
```

and the partial is;

```
<% cache lesson do %>
    <div class="video_size">
       <video controls class='video_size'>
          <source src=<%= rails_blob_path(lesson.video) %> type='video/mp4' />
       </video>
     </div>
<% end -%>
```

I would like to store a count of how often each video is actually played, i.e the play button in the video is pressed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my opinion, if you want to count or store how often each video actually saw, you should custom to track

```
ActiveStorage::YourController at 'show' action
```

Like that:

```
# In app/controllers/active_storage/base_controller.rb
class ActiveStorage::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :your_implemnt_method!
  include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def your_implemnt_method!
     ## check what the video you want to increment.
     # and increment number of seen in model via direct for queue it to backgroud worker
     content.plus_seen
     # do something more.

  end
end
```

to couter_cache or increment the number of viewers, ...etc

Another solution is: you want to count the number of times the play button on clicked, just using javascript handle click event, so that send the ajax request to to controller to increment the count.

[image]

JS code handle play

```
const player = new Plyr('#player');
$('.plyr__control[data-plyr="play"]').click(function() {
  if (!player.source){

    Rails.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/url-to-do-sth",
      data: {your_data: data-to-sent},
      success: function(repsonse){
      },
      error: function(repsonse){
        console.log(repsonse);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

And in your controller:

```
def handle-sth
  begin
    ## Do sothing
    # and increment number of seen in model via direct for queue it to backgroud worker
    content.plus_seen

    render json: {data: data-to-sent}
  rescue
    render :json => { :errors => ["Error with encode or decode."] }, :status => 422
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want to count the number of times the play button on clicked, just using javascript handle click event, so that send the ajax request to to controller to increment the count.

Comment: @Obromios, please check my edited post for implement something I was recommended before.